# How can we have usability and UX tests around PAN (personal area network) gadgets interfaces?

Tags: usability, usability-testing

Our gadgets around us are changing and I think that it will continue for a while. I really wonder if there is a nice example about usability and overall experience testing methods for Personal area network gadgets, **especially head positioned visual ones,glasses**.

For instance, eye-tracking was a method for usability testing before but now eye movements are changing pages or even an action for the device itself. Ergonomics are another perspective that we can rely on but could not find any study about the comfortable eye movements while there are many studies about tracking cursor and movements.

Edit:

What kind of methodologies can it be used while transferring an existing solution to another device level (PAN) and also protecting the overall user experience? Ergonomically, do they have constraints and if yes, what are they?

Comment: Could you make your question a bit clearer? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What kind of methodologies can it be used while transferring an existing solution to another device level (PAN) and also protecting the overall user experience? Ergonomically, do they have constraints and if yes, what are they?

Comment: @Abektes - you can edit your question and add that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either diary studies or living lab tests.

Diary studies is essentially calling / otherwise reminding a participant at regular intervals to express their feelings and thoughts towards the system which is tested.

Living lab is basically a Big Brother-style living environment for short or extended periods of time.

Since the ethical (and financial) investment and concerns around a living lab is huge, I suggest you do diary studies.

I first read about these in the ID book ( http://www.id-book.com ) many-many years ago, but the net is full of resources on how to do UX Diary Studies, what to look for, etc - for example, UXBooth ran cool articles about it.

An example could be that

1. you give the prototype to the users for a day, first trying out in a room in front of a visible - and visibly recording - camera, while also recording the output of the tools, and you observe them using it
2. then let them out to their own environment, asking them how they feel about it each hour through whatsapp or similar, or even calling them by phone.
3. Have a summary interview when they give back the tool (which should be within hours after last using it

We were thinking about having people interviewed this way, but haven't implemented in practice yet.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i somehow managed it with wizard of OZ with a time period. it was for behavioral change goal project

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple observation with a following interview, which definitely works, but result accuracy is low. If you can get hold of a Mood Meter from MIT and track it's time stamp when user interacts with the glasses it would be awesome.

[image]

Reference: [MIT Mood Meter](http://moodmeter.media.mit.edu)

Comment: I think that measuring emotional satisfaction is one perspective. Let's take snapping a photo as an action. It can be still done with a handheld device however, we can also take the same action with Google glass. The form of the action will be different. There should be a measuring tool that provides information of location, app(used service) and usage of the action itself while taking some time references. It should be there because of business validations of big companies. Let's see if someone will share it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but today I found this book, which is about designing emerging technologies.

[http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Emerging-Technologies-Genomics-Robotics/dp/1449370519](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449370519)